# Designing layout android

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I am currently trying to create a list view which will show details about a post. For that, I have created xml file for designing the list item.

[image]

This is the final look I want for my activity. So far I have succeeded dealing with the rounded corners, image buttons and the texts, but I am trying for a while to deal with the left side of the text box. I want it to have a sharp tip. But I still can't handle it.

I will add the xml files to show what I did.

```
**This is the xml file for the list item**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/desclayout"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_my_posts_selector"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myPostDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxLength="120"
            android:hint="@string/description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="4"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textColorHint="#f7941e"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="#6d6e71"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="14sp">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/desclayout"
        android:background="@drawable/description_layout_my_posts_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/acceptMyPostBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_posts_button_selector"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/v"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/closeMyPostBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_posts_button_selector"
            android:layout_below="@id/acceptMyPostBtn"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/x"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/showOnMapMyPost"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:background="@drawable/my_posts_button_selector"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/desclayout"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:background="#2d2d2d"
        android:layout_height="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:text="Finished at 19/01/2013 13:55"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_my_posts_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#f1f1f2"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"  android:color="#2d2d2d" />

    <corners android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"/>

    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

**description_layout_my_posts_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#e7e8ea"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#2d2d2d" />
    <corners android:topRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

This is how it currently looks[image]

If you can please guide me how to deal with the sharp tip I will be thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using a separate background xml file is a good idea, i would suggest that you use a drawable instead for background.
So you can design your background image with the 'sharp tip' on the left in photoshop or paint.net and set the property `android:background=@drawable/background_design` where 'background design' is the name of your design drawable file.

Programming it will take more resources to render the design. Not a good practice to use in a listview. For best performance go for a drawable for a static layout.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't understand why my post have got -1,

but anyway I will post the way I chose to do it.

I have crated xml file named: triangle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="87%"
            android:pivotY="115%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#f1f1f2"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

After this I have added linear layout to my list_item_xml with
the background of the triangle xml.

Thanks for your help, have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

[image: Use This 9 Patch Image] You can use 9 patch as a background.Create one [here](http://draw9patch.com/)

Comment: your answer is ok but you should give a reason why not in xml or programmatic level and have to mention any possibility is there or not.

Comment: Everything is possible if you are ready to code.
I showed you the easiest way to implement it.
Check [this](https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter) Project.